# Why is this bad API design?

Tags: .net, rest, architecture, api-design

We have a single .NET API that manages all requests for multiple applications. The API uses `System.Data.SqlClient` to speak to the database rather than using an Entity Framework "bridge".

Its endpoints are all generic -- I mean that in the most literal sense. We have a single `Get()`, a single `UpdateInsert()`, and a single `Delete()` endpoint. In the HTTP request, we send a SQL query and a list of parameters. When the API was written, the developers were relatively inexperienced and were bred on SQL connectors rather than EF. All of the queries are parameterised, so I don't think there's a risk of SQL injection.

For example:

```
public static ReturnedObject Upsert(string sql, Dictionary<string,string> parameters, int applicationID)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringProvider.Retrieve(applicationID));
                
    connection.Open();

    string valueToReturn = "";
                
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> valuePair in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(valuePair.Key, valuePair.Value);
                }

                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                            
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    // Assign result to valueToReturn
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Assign exception to valueToReturn
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Assign exception to valueToReturn
    }

    // Return valueToReturn
}
```

My question is: can you help me explain why this is bad API design? Here is what I've been able to come up with so far with my clean architecture hat on:

- Violates single responsibility principle (one API p/responsibility)
- Raw SQL exposes information about database implementation (is having raw SQL in an HTTP request also a security concern?)
- Use of SqlClient sets database implementation in stone
- Does not encourage best practice architecture design within its client applications

I'm sure there are other things that I'm missing. I've never seen an API like this before, and I'd like to know why.

Comment: How about user rights? Every user can manipulate the whole database? It is not (easy) possible to distinguish rights between different tables.

Answer (score 1):

> All of the queries are parameterised, so I don't think there's a risk of SQL injection.

You should not be afraid of SQL injection when your API allows to execute ANY arbitrary SQL. The API does not enforce usage of parameterization so it can't prevent a malicious (or not) user to just use string concatenation to build the query with all the corresponding consequences.

Rest of the problems are less important but still to name a few:

1. There is no an easy way to (partially) restrict access
2. There is no an easy way to perform query validation (you will need to parse it)
3. Clients need to know about internal service details (i.e. how data is stored and what query language to use) rather than using "strongly-defined" contracts
4. You are using `AddWithValue`:

   - [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)
   - [AddWithValue performance and plan cache implications](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications)

Comment: "You should not be afraid of SQL injection when your API allows to execute ANY arbitrary SQL" you should, because SQL injection is also about *correctness* as much as *security*, so even a non-malicious user could easily make a mistake if you are injecting incorrectly.

Comment: @Charlieface TBH do not fully agree. The main point was that API provides an ability to pass parameters but in no way or form enforces it, i.e. correctness is at the same risk if non-malicious user misuses the API by not using parameterization.

Comment: OK so we agree, except you haven't worded that right, as it sounds like SQL injection isn't a problem from your current wording.

Comment: @Charlieface yes, exactly. I used it because it was explicitly brought up by OP.

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron. You said "to name a few". If you have any more, that would be great.

Comment: @Panko in general I would argue that this is already should be enough. Especially the starting one and the point # 3. Also while I don't fully agree with _"Use of SqlClient sets database implementation in stone"_ statement as expansion of point 3 - you still limit possible used technologies due to possible usage of SQL Server specific syntax and  making it quite harder to switch to another relational database (and impossible to switch to NoSQL one for example).

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following to the above concerns:

1. It is hard to cover with unit tests. This fact makes your software less modifiable.
2. `UpdateInsert` - perhaps, violates the SRP, there should be one method for update , another one for insert.
3. What if you need to change the database? What if your clients should be provided with data from different databases? This current implementation does not support this kind of functionality extension.
4. Also, I'd like to notice that exception handling looks ugly.